# How solve problem: There was 1 unclosed DO block?

Tags: sas

I have a below code in the SAS:

```
proc sort data=MYDATA1;
by VarNum Size Flavour Brand Retailer Market date; 
run; 
DATA MYDATA;
SET MYDATA1;
by VarNum Brand Size Flavour Retailer Market date; 
/* Loop while for transformations. */
SUM = 0;
VAR1 = 1;
V1= Transformation;
VAR = Variable_for_SAS;
DO WHILE(FIND(V1,";")<>0);

V=V1;

V1=substr(V1,1,FIND(V1,";")-1);

IF SUBSTR(V1,1,1)="/" THEN

VT=STRIP(SUBSTR(V1,2,Find(V1,";")-2))||STRIP(date);

if _n_=1 then do;
    declare hash h(dataset: 'MYDATA1');
    h.definekey('Variable_date');
    h.definedata('Variable_for_SAS');
    h.definedone();
end;
  if not h.find(key: VT) then new=Variable_for_SAS;
  h.find();

SUM1=1*VAR;
/*Overwrite variable*/
VAR=SUM1;

V1=substr(TRIM(V),FIND(V,";")+1);
run;
```

But I have error:

```
run;
              _
              117
ERROR 117-185: There was 1 unclosed DO block.
```

Do you know what I should do to solve this problem?
Is problem because I use DO WHILE and hash together?
Now code is full.

Comment: Please show the full data step. The top is cut off.

Comment: Now code is full.

Comment: The error is clear, so fix that. But what is the purpose of the code?

Answer (score 2):

Just add in the missing `END` statement for where you want your `DO WHILE ()` loop to end.

Because you could be looping multiple times on even the first iteration of the data step your IF condition to run the hash creation steps is not sufficient to make sure those statements only run once. So either move the block that creates the HASH object to BEFORE the while loop. Or add additional conditions to the IF statement to keep it from re-running on every iteration of the DO WHILE loop.